# Vhdl Parallel or Serial-in/ Parallel-out register

Tags: vhdl

I want to build a n bits register which can take both serial or parallel input depending of a bit SERIAL. And always parallel output. See my code below. My issue is that I need to use a If statement to choose my input (parallel or serial) (which must be inside a process) and I also need a for generate statement because I work with generic n bit register (which cannot be done inside a process) to build the n D-Flipflop.

I was thinking to use for loop instead of for i ..generate but I need to use that i as index.
Does anyone know how to fix my code? The main issue is that using serial input, the flipflop are connected in series while parallel input, the flipflops are independent. And I don't know how to model that proprely.

Thank you

```
-- Parallel or Serial-in / Parallel-out n bits register
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity PSIPOreg is
    generic(n: integer);
    port(RST, Clk_reg, enable, SERIAL: in std_logic;
        Din_P: in std_logic_vector(n-1 downto 0);
        Din_S: in std_logic;
        Qout: out std_logic_vector(n-1 downto 0));
end PSIPOreg;

architecture bhv of PSIPOreg is
component D_FlipFlop 
    port(D, Clk, reset, EN : in std_logic;
        Q : out std_logic);
end component;

signal parallel_data : std_logic_vector(0 to n-1) := (others =>'0');
signal temp_input: std_logic_vector(0 to n-1) := (others =>'0');
begin
    Qout <= parallel_data;
    process(SERIAL, Clk_reg, enable, RST)
    begin
    if(SERIAL = '0') then -- PIPO register
        temp_input <= Din_P;
        gen_reg: for i in 0 to n-1 generate
            regx: D_FlipFlop port map(D => temp_input(i), Clk => Clk_reg, reset => RST, EN => enable, Q => Qout(i));
        end generate gen_reg;

    elsif(SERIAL = '1') then -- SIPO register
        temp_input(0) <= Din_S;
        shift_reg: for i in 0 to n-1 generate
            begin
            dff_lsb: if i = 0 generate
                begin
                dff: D_FlipFlop port map(D => temp_input(0), Clk => Clk_reg, reset => RST, EN => enable, Q => parallel_data(i));
                --Qout(i) <= parallel_data(i);
            end generate dff_lsb;
            dff_mid: if((i>0) and (i<(n-1))) generate
                begin
                dff: D_FlipFlop port map(D => parallel_data(i-1), Clk => Clk_reg, reset => RST, EN => enable, Q => parallel_data(i));
                --Qout(i) <= parallel_data(i);
                end generate dff_mid;
            dff_msb: if i = n-1 generate
                begin
                dff: D_FlipFlop port map(D => parallel_data(i-1), Clk => Clk_reg, reset => RST, EN => enable, Q => Qout(i));
            end generate dff_msb;
        end generate shift_reg;
    end if;
    end process;
end bhv;
```

Comment: For loops can be used inside a process. Generate loops cannot.   Component instantiation cannot be used inside process.  Do you have a drawing of your intended circuit? Try to work out your circuit before writing code.

Comment: By putting your flip-flop instantiations inside a process, you are trying to create flip-flips that (somehow magically) appear and disappear depending on whether the input `SERIAL` is high or low. HW can't do that. An instantiation is not a function call, it is like soldering a chip to a PCB. As Tricky says, design your circuit first before starting your VHDL. (Experienced VHDL engineers always do that. They might not literally draw the circuit diagram, but as they write their code they know roughly what HW they are expecting. If they don't know that, they're not doing it properly.)

Comment: @Tricky How can I use a for i in to n-1 loop where n is generic  when I need to use the iteration variable i as index during the port map?

Comment: @MatthewTaylor I basically need n mux controlled by SERIAL bit that have as output the input of the next Dflipflop and as input either one bit of the stf_logic_vector when using in parallel or the output of the last Dflipflop. I though it would be done during the synthesis. Since it is clear that I need n Dflipflop or what only changes it the connection between them.

Comment: @Saens If you're doing a port map, then you're doing an instantiation which cannot be done in procedural code, so you will not be using a for loop. You can use a generate loop though.

Comment: An [alternative architecture for PSIPOreg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ivrcB.jpg). With an enabled flip flop SERIAL should selected between the parallel load value Din_P and a shfited parallel_data sliced value concatenated with Din_S. Without a working implementation of the original architecture  or specification the shift direction can't be verified.